# Transition when switching Activity out of SlidingMenu (J.Feinstein)

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am an android newbie and I am trying to create an Android App with three Activities: a Homescreen, a listview and a detailview.

I integrated J. Feinstein's Sliding Menu in my Homescreen and filled it with a ListView to display my different categories (Restaurants, Bars, Culture, whatever). When I click one of my List Items, the new Activity gets created and Pops up. However, I want the Activity to replace the old one while the SlidingMenu stays on top and then gently slides away. I saw this behaviour in the Example App but I cant quite find the bit of code that holds the answer to my question. Hope anyone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

The sample app uses fragment transactions instead of starting new activities to change the content. As far as I know, that is the only way to do the two actions – close sliding menu and change content – simultaneously.